# How to populate List<int> from List<class> that contains int variable in getter

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, getter-setter

For example:

```cs
public List<Data> dataList;
public List<int> idList;

public class Data
{
  public int id;
  public string name;
}
```

I need to get all 'id' variables from 'dataList' into 'idList'.
Something like that

```cs
public List<Data> dataList;
public List<int> idList
{
 get 
 {
   for (int i = 0; i < dataList.Count; i++)
   {
     idList.Add(dataList[i].id);
   }

   return idList
 }
};
```

But how to optimize this in a better way?

I tried to create local list, populate it with ids and then give it to the 'idList'. But I think this method is not optimized

Comment: Using LINQ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/. In this case `idList = dataList.Select(d => d.id).ToList();`

Comment: I would argue that without a very good reason, you should not do such a thing at all, since the data already exists in your class and is easily accessible.

Comment: `But how to optimize this in a better way?` .. you mean how to make it not end in an exception in the first place? ;) Currently you recursively access `idList` within the getter ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Linq `Select` for that

```cs
public List<Data> dataList;
public List<int> idList
{
  get 
  {
    return dataList.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
  };
}
```

in more compact way

```cs
public List<int> idList => dataList.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
```

More about LINQ [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/).

Comment: Thanks, thats what i wanted. Forgot about LINQ at all. Tried to complete in a usual way.

Comment: Most welcome my friend @КириллДосын

Comment: This is indeed what I would do ..@КириллДосын note however that this is in now way different than writing it "by hand" .. it is as efficient as writing the thing out with a for loop (or would be if you initialized the list with the correct capacity) ;)